# Execute background process in python

Tags: python, azure-functions, multiprocessing, azure-cosmosdb, python-asyncio

In python, I am trying to run a process (storing huge amount of data to db) as a background process and it should not wait to return the response of current executing function. I tried the below code. But its not working as my expectation. I will explain my real problem. If I get an alternate solution for my real problem also would be very helpful.

Actually my problem is I am using Azure cosmos db and function app. If I need to process huge amount of data in the cosmos db, I am getting Batch Write Error. So I tried to insert data batch by batch with the 2 sec interval. If I do this, the whole process execution time is crossing over 2 min, then my function app getting failed due to 2 min time out. Thats why I tried this db update to be executed in a separate process. But If anything fails in the independent thread execution, I need to send an email saying the db update is failed.

```
async def import_and_background_task(myobj):
    asyncio.ensure_future(myobj.storeDataToDb())

def exectuteReport():
    myobj.readInputFile()
    myobj.readDatafromDb()
    myobj.generateReport()
    # myobj.storeDataToDb()
    asyncio.run(import_and_background_task(myobj))
    print('its done')
    return {success:True}
```

Sample definition of `storeDataToDb` function is,

```
def storeDataToDb():
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        print('storing set {} of data to db'.format(count))
        count += 1
        time.sleep(2)  # Delays for 2 seconds. You can adjust as needed.
```

I am expecting it will return the {success:True} immediately not waiting to print `storing set {} of data to db`. But its waiting to complete all the works of `storeDataToDb`. How can I run this storeDataToDb function as a background process?

Comment: Nope, that's not how `async` works, despite the name.  If you have an I/O bound process, you can use a thread.  If it is compute-bound, you may need to use multiprocessing.

Comment: Is this "fire and forget" or does the process that invokes the job need to eventually get notified. If the former I'd be tempted to create an entirely separate script, and invoke it using `subprocess.Popen`. If the latter I tend to use `celery` for things like this (but there's a bit of a learning curve)

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread like so:

```
from threading import Thread

t = Thread(target=myobj.storeDataToDb)
t.start()
```

Keep in mind that if the majority of the code is CPU-bound in Python, it's better to use a process, but that would be considerably more difficult with a class like mentioned. I don't suppose it's the issue as storing data to a DB is mostly IO.

If it happens multiple times in the code, I suggest using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) for some more robust executors and queuing of tasks.

Lastly, this does not handle a case of the target code getting stuck if anything weird happens, but I wouldn't switch to a daemon thread as it might lose data. Dealing with this is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Actually my problem is I am using Azure cosmos db and function app. If I need to process huge amount of data in the cosmos db, I am getting Batch Write Error. So I tried to insert data batch by batch with the 2 sec interval. If I do this, the whole process execution time is crossing over 2 min, then my function app getting failed due to 2 min time out. Thats why I tried to the db update as separate process. Your last point is really matter to me, I need to send an email if anything fails in the independent thread. I will edit this to question too.

Comment: @SmithDwayne that's a completely different story and will require an in-depth explanation. The easy fix is to wrap the threaded function and mail on errors, but I don't think Azure will let you continue running the function after returning a response, in which case you'll have to resort to queuing tasks in Azure. It sounds like you're doing something wrong though. It's hard to know what exactly does the function do and why does it process so much data.